# App description is not showing in tab configuration page header MS Bot for Teams (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When the tab configuration page is loaded the description that I have added in AppDetails is not showing beside my app icon like it is shown for trello. I dont see anywhere in the docs regarding this.

[image]  [image]

I would be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is by design.Quite a while back we started giving developers more control (and vertical pixels) in the tab configuration flow and allow them to render their own description within the iframe. Everything within that header area is now controlled by the app. App description appears on click of about link.